# How to set default controller in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Is there a way to specify a default controller in Yii? Instead of using the SiteController? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To set your default controller as your homepage's controller on Yii PHP-Framework.  You must modify the core defaults controller (site/index) on your /protected/config/main.php

```
return array(
    'name' => 'Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'home ', 

);
```

Comment: DefaultController will simply be called when you call yoursite/yourmodule. You don't need to change its name to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

try to add the configuration in the config main.php

```
'defaultController' => 'newcontrollername',
```

after 'name' setting.

Answer (score -2):

also there is another way to do that

change the values of public $defaultController property in

framework/web/CWebApplication.php

Comment: You shouldn't edit files that are part of the framework because they may change during an update and your changes lost.