# where we can specify default controller and action in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have created one project in yii and my default controller points to site controller . I  want to change it with some other and where i can specify default controller and action in yii.

Comment: default controller/first controller in yii is **site controller** because its view is "site"

Comment: Try this in config 'defaultController' => 'myController'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default controller in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373057/how-to-set-default-controller-in-yii)

Answer (score 15):

add the configuration in the config main.php

```
return array(
    'name' => 'Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'home', 
    ......
);
```

Comment: You can also specify an action along with the controller name, e.g. `home/index`.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect solution for changing the default controller. Part of the question was also to change the default action. If you've set `'defaultController' => 'home',` the default action will be `'index' (unless set otherwise)`, you can change this in the controller like so:

```
class HomeController extends CController
{

  public $defaultAction = 'someotheraction';

  public function actionSomeotheroaction()
  {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add any where in return array  protected/main.php

```
return array(
    ......
    'defaultController' => 'index', 
    ......
);
```

if you are working in modules base then you can add

```
'defaultController' => 'shop/index',
```

Shop is module and index is controller

Answer (score 0):

You can set controller to Default Controller in project directory protected/main.php
add this code in array like $configArray =  array()

```
$configArray =  array
(
    'name'=>'Web Appname',
    'defaultController'=>'index'
    ......
);
```

And set the default action in Controller

```
class NameController extends AdminCoreController
{
    public $defaultAction = 'index'; 
}
```