# How to access Yii module from root folder

Tags: php, yii, yii-modules

I am creating an application installer which i need to access from application root folder.

This is my installer http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/databaseinstaller/

I want to use this installer from root , not from module folder.

Please help me out for the same.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add  this rule in  urlManager in main.php , ( installer is module name in the databaseinstaller module )

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                'installer'=>'installer/installer/index',
                  .....,
                  ..... ,
            ),
```

Now you can access the installer from your root Url

```
www.yourdomain.com/installer
```

Comment: I want to keep my module folder "installer" in my root directory.

Comment: you mean the place where index.php exist

Comment: Yes, I want to please there.

Comment: what do  you want exactly ? why do you want to move the files ? if you want to run the installer when you hit www.yourdomain.com , you can set default controller in the main.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008453/where-we-can-specify-default-controller-and-action-in-yii

Comment: I want to keep my module folder named "installer" in root directory, not in modules folder under protected/modules. So when i will run www.yourdomain.com/installer. It should run like a module.

Comment: There is one possibility , you can copy  module/ (controllers,models,views )  to protected controllers ,models,views files respectively.  There is no other possibility